# Tell WP to use a specific template file in posts

Tags: posts, customization, templates

I've searched everywhere and tried a couple plugins with no success. I'm using WP 3.9.1.

I have to create different ways to show my posts. If they are "standard" they use the single-post.php. That's ok.

If they have an image gallery, I want to change the whole structure. 
Same thing if they contain a video. I want to change the html structure.

So, instead of creating different custom post types, a thing that creates other problems down the line to take care of, I just want to be able to say to wp "hey, use this template file".

How can I be able to do that? I guess it's about making wp asking the editor "for this post, what template you want to use?" in admin.

Comment: Have you tried using post formats? http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Comment: I tried. I added `add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'photopost', 'videopost' ) );` in functions.php. I also added `add_post_type_support( 'photopost', 'post-formats' );
add_post_type_support( 'videopost', 'post-formats' );` in functions.php.

The post edit page show a "format" section, but it only has "standard" as option.

Comment: Oh, and I also created a photopost-template.php and videopost-template.php files. Both with their own `/*
Template Name: [..]
*/`

Comment: Oooooooh now I get it. There is no such thing as custom post formats, is it?

Comment: Go and see how the bundled themes make use of post formats. I suggest that you activate twentyfourteen on a local install and play arount with post formats which is activated by default in the twentyfourteen theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for getting post format, simple made condition if post format ="standard" then load your preferred template

```
 $format = get_post_format();
if($format ="video")
{
get_template_part( 'format', $format );
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: With something like that I made it work. Inside the **single-post.php** file i put that kind of conditions after the loop. Something like: 
`if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
 //put the html/php for the video format
}
elseif ( has_post_format('gallery')) {
 // put the html/php for the gallery format
}
else {
 //put the html/php for the standard post format
}
`